# Problem with macro expansion when making a custom queue container

Tags: macros, expansion, etoolbox

I'm trying to make a simple queue using the `etoolbox` package by making my own custom macros `\listfront` and `\listfrontpop`. This is my very first time using TeX code to this level, so my understanding is tenuous at best. Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\listfront}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{##1\listbreak}%
  \dolistloop{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\listpopfront}[1]{%
  \def\templistfront{\listfront{#1}}%
  \listgremove{#1}{\templistfront}%
}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\mylist}{}%
  \listgadd{\mylist}{potty}%
  \listgadd{\mylist}{sam}%
  \listfront{\mylist}%       potty   <- as expected
  \listpopfront{\mylist}%    potty should be removed
  \listfront{\mylist}%       potty   <- expected sam!
\end{document}
```

I expect to get `pottysam`, but get `pottypotty` instead. I *suspect* that the issue lies with the line

```
...
\begin{document}
...
  \listpopfront{\mylist}%
...
\end{document}
```

because if I replace it with `\listgremove{\mylist}{potty}`, I do get `pottysam`. However, if I do something like `\def\potty{potty}` and then do `\listgremove{\mylist}{\potty}`, I get `pottypotty` once again.

How do I get `\listpopfront` to work? What is going wrong?

So far, my solution is to have `\listpopfront` defined as

```
\newcommand{\listpopfront}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
    \listgremove{#1}{##1}\listbreak%
  }%
  \dolistloop{#1}%
}
```

which solves my problem, but is incredibly inelegant.

Comment: Use `\documentclass{article}` for testing purposes. `minimal` is for developers. `\newcommand{\mylist}{}` should probably be placed in the preamble.

Comment: I had not read your solution near bottom of your question (before posting my answer),  from which you say it is "incredibly inelegant" but I disagree, it is rather clever.  I would say it is a bit lucky it works because redefining the list from inside a parsing of itself was not guaranteed to work, but it turns out etoolbox internal structure is not complex and this works.

Comment: about `\listgremove{\mylist}{\potty}` etoolbox will try to remove an item `\potty` not its expansion.  As you have added the string `potty` not the macro `\potty` to the list it is normal etoolbox does not detect the macro `\potty` as being among the list items.

Comment: @user691586 maybe it is elegant after all, but I still would like to know how to remove the expansion of `\potty` for future references, or reuse already existing macros.

Comment: @daedsidog Using the `etoolbox` interface `\listgremove` to remove the "expansion of `\potty`" the issue is that you will have to pass this expanded content to `\listgremove`.  For example `\expandafter\listgremove\expandafter{\expandafter\mylist\expandafter}\expandafter{\potty}` does this.  Shorter `\expanded`: `\expanded{\unexpanded{\listgremove{\mylist}}{\potty}}` (available since 2019 in TeX engines, earlier in LuaTeX).  Other techniques apply, look in my code with `\x`.

Comment: @user691586 Thank you, both these examples work and is exactly what I was after.

Comment: @daedsidog glad it works for you. The `\expanded` way is more powerful because if the first argument of `\listgremove` was not a single token `\mylist` as here but say `thenameofsomething` (which no `\ `at start) we would have to `\expandafter` each single letter of this thing, and you don't want to have to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is as solution which uses only the documentation of etoolbox and none of its internals, and develops from your MWE.  I allowed myself usage of `\def` as you already used it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\listfront}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{##1\listbreak}%
  \dolistloop{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\listpopfront}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \long\def\do##1{\long\def\templistfront{##1}\listbreak}%
  \dolistloop{#1}%
  \def\x{\endgroup\listgremove{#1}}%
  \expandafter\x\expandafter{\templistfront}%
}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\mylist}{}%
  \listgadd{\mylist}{potty}%
  \listgadd{\mylist}{sam}%
  \listfront{\mylist}%       potty   <- as expected
  \listpopfront{\mylist}%    potty should be removed
  \listfront{\mylist}%       sam     <- as expected
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am surprised etoolbox does not provided a "pop" for that purpose, because the usage of `\listgremove` looked to me potentially very inefficient but I checked a macro trace and I see it is based on using `\ifinlist` which uses delimited macros, not an item by item check, and besides it only removes the first found item (the documentation is not clear on that but I conclude from checking expansion).

Note that LaTeX kernel already has built-in tools `\@car`, `\@cdr` and `\@tfor` (not to mention the LaTeX3 now incorporated layer...) which you could use to build your own, but I guess it is logical to use `etoolbox` if you plan on invoking its `\dolistloop`.

Here is now code which uses the internal etoolbox structure.  Fortunately, it is very simple and straightforward, but should it change in future, this code will be broken.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% this command is only good for typesetting,
% it does not work expandably
\newcommand{\listfront}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{##1\listbreak}%
  \dolistloop{#1}%
}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
% definition of a "popfront" as per OP command name
% it removes the first item globally
\catcode`\|=3 % internal separator used by etoolbox
\gdef\listpopfront#1{%
  \expandafter\listpopfront@i#1\@nil{#1}%
}
\long\gdef\listpopfront@i#1|#2\@nil#3{\long\gdef#3{#2}}

% we also define for the fun an expandable \listexpandablefront
% now that we are using internals of etoolbox
\gdef\listexpandablefront#1{%
  \expandafter\listexpandablefront@i#1\@nil
}
\long\gdef\listexpandablefront@i#1|#2\@nil{#1}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\mylist}{}%
  \listgadd{\mylist}{potty}%
  \listgadd{\mylist}{sam}%
% \show\mylist
  \listfront{\mylist}%       potty   <- as expected
  \listpopfront{\mylist}%    potty should be removed
% \show\mylist
  \listfront{\mylist}%       sam    <- as expected

  \edef\foo{\listexpandablefront{\mylist}}
  \texttt{\meaning\foo}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot with macro meaning]

Comment: after posting my answer I saw OP had already a working solution for `\listpopfront` which I must admit is rather more elegant than the one I posted in code at top of my answer, and basically boils down to same thing, as allowed by surprisingly limited set of tools provided by `etoolbox` for its "internal lists".  In pratice it may be important to have an expandable way to extract the first list item, and this what my second code does.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want FIFO lists. I'd use `expl3` rather than `etoolbox`; note that list names are without a backslash, which avoids the problem of choosing command names.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%%% the user level commands

% declare a list and optionally add items
\NewDocumentCommand{\declarelist}{mo}
 {
  \daedsidog_list_declare:n { #1 }
  \IfValueT{#2}
   {
    \daedsidog_list_gadd:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
% add items to a list
\NewDocumentCommand{\listgadd}{mm}
 {
  \daedsidog_list_gadd:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
% deliver the front item (this is expandable)
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\listfront}{m}
 {
  \daedsidog_list_front:n { #1 }
 }
% pop the front item
\NewDocumentCommand{\listpopfront}{m}
 {
  \daedsidog_list_popfront:n { #1 }
 }

%%% the internal functions

% declare a list
\cs_new_protected:Nn \daedsidog_list_declare:n
 {
  \seq_new:c { g__daedsidog_list_#1_seq }
 }
% add items to a list
\cs_new_protected:Nn \daedsidog_list_gadd:nn
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g__daedsidog_list_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }
% deliver the front item
\cs_new:Nn \daedsidog_list_front:n
 {
  \seq_item:cn { g__daedsidog_list_#1_seq } { 1 }
 }
% pop the front item
\cs_new_protected:Nn \daedsidog_list_popfront:n
 {
  \seq_gpop_left:cN { g__daedsidog_list_#1_seq } \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\declarelist{mylist}[potty,sam]

% could also be
%\declarelist{mylist}
%\listgadd{potty,sam}
% or
%\declarelist{mylist}
%\listgadd{potty}
%\listgadd{sam}

\begin{document}

\listfront{mylist}%       potty   <- as expected
\listpopfront{mylist}%    potty should be removed
\listfront{mylist}%       potty   <- expected sam!

\end{document}
```

You can add more than one item at a time (also when declaring a list).

[image]